# Session gets lost when a user closes their browser

Tags: 7, users, sessions

When user login, I am creating cookie till a certain date. When the browser tab is closed while the user is logged in, the session remains. But when we quit the browser, the session is lost and user has to login again even if the cookie exists. What is causing this?

Comment: You need to state your question more clearly.